# Jenkins slave job with two git repos

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to setup master/slave on two osx machines, while using only slave for build.

Have one main git repo for the project but few additional files are kept in separate git repository. After adding two git repositories noticed after checkout it's creating two project directories under workspace and one has "@2" in the name.
That makes a problem with copying/accessing files between two repositories using $WORKSPACE variable as directory "project_name@2" is not logically part or $WORKSPACE (getting file not found error). And also cannot know which repo will be in which directory with every new build.
And more confusing sometimes it even pulls one repo to the master machine even though I've set that the build executes only on slave.

I'd appreciate any advice or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the GIT plugin you can use advance cloning settings and specify a sub folder to clone to. make sure to clone to different folders under your workspace and then you can access both. I'm doing that in some of my projects and it works like a charm.

Use : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multiple+SCMs+Plugin

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the tip but still not sure how to apply it.
I'm using git plugin and have option to add multiple repositories, but adding sub directory option is not available for each repo as it is added after both repository definition.
In the log it shows it's fetching both repos but then there's only one in defined sub directory. Second repo is missing

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
That's the one I needed and "it works like a charm".